# Where to define variable working with function

Tags: python, variables

Having trouble trying to print the "score" variable that is defined in the "question" function.
The troubling code in question:

```
def question(attempt, answer):
    score = 0
        #if attempt is true, add 1 to score
        #if attempt is false, do nothing to score
    if attempt == answer:
        score += 1

print("How many ducks are there?")
question(input(), "14")

print("Your score is %r." % score)
```

Although, when I try to run it, all I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quiz.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("Your score is %r." % score)
NameError: name 'score' is not defined
```

Any help with figuring out where to place the variable would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def question(attempt, answer):
    score = 0
    #if attempt is true, add 1 to score
    #if attempt is false, do nothing to score
    if attempt == answer:
        score += 1
        return score
    print("Your score is %r." % score)
```

I would print it inside the function, which returns:

```
>>> print("How many ducks are there?")
How many ducks are there?
>>> question(input(), "14")

Your score is 0.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent the code which is running in your function, also you have to return some value from your function

```
def question(attempt, answer):
    score = 0
    #if attempt is true, add 1 to score
    #if attempt is false, do nothing to score
    if attempt == answer:
        score = 1
    return score
```

You should count a global score outside of the function i.e.
`score += question(attempt, answer)`